# Issue with multiple records showing for a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of comics with a table of comics, credits, and contributor details. I am trying to filter my table using this SQL query:

**The select parameters have * to show all but don't seem to show here**

```
SELECT
   cc.*,
   ct.*,
   cpub.*,
   c.*,
   cs.* 
FROM
   comic_types AS ct,
   comics_publisher AS cpub,
   comics AS c,
   comics_series AS cs,
   comic_credits AS cc 
WHERE
   c.comic_indexkey = cc.comic_index_key 
   AND cpub.publisher_index_key = c.comic_publisher 
   AND c.comic_series = cs.comics_seriesindexkey 
   AND ct.comic_typeindexkey = c.comic_type 
   AND cpub.publisher_index_key = c.comic_publisher 
ORDER BY
   comic_title ASC,
   comic_series ASC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

The Limit values are placed there for pagination.

Some comics have the same contributor with a different role (e.g. comic A has person B as author and illustrator). This means I have two results that are the same comic. I have used an array and continue statement to make the duplicate record not show.

```
$comics_in_table = array();
if (in_array($comic['comic_indexkey'], $comics_in_table)) {
    continue;
}
```

The problem this has created is the pagination only shows 5 per page rather than 15, presumably because it detects that 10 of the results have been 'hidden'

Following the kind help so far, created this:

```
SELECT
   cc.*,
   ct.*,
   cpub.*,
   c.*,
   cs.* 
FROM
   comic_types AS ct,
   comics_publisher AS cpub,
   comics AS c,
   comics_series AS cs,
   comic_credits AS cc 
WHERE
   c.comic_indexkey = cc.comic_index_key 
   AND cpub.publisher_index_key = c.comic_publisher 
   AND c.comic_series = cs.comics_seriesindexkey 
   AND ct.comic_typeindexkey = c.comic_type 
   AND cpub.publisher_index_key = c.comic_publisher 
GROUP BY
   cc.comic_index_key 
ORDER BY
   c.comic_title ASC,
   c.comic_series ASC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

And SQL returns this issue:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sewters.cc.credit_index_key' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Add the distinct keyword to your query: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try either to use

`SELECT DISTINCT cc.*, ct.* ...`

or append a

`GROUP BY fieldname`

at the end of your SELECT query, where `fieldname` is the database column that you want grouped into one entry.